# How do I add data from a CSV file to an array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, csv, file-writing

I've searched and searched online, but nothing I do seems to work. I'm aware that this is a stupidly easy question, but I'm really stuck...

I had a directory of files, and saved the names of the directories to a CSV file. It's just made up of one column of data e.g.:

```
100
101
102
103...
```

I used the following code to create the file (just in case its relevant):

```
open (my $fileh, '>', '/Users/Shared/serials.csv') or die "Could not open file!";
print $fileh `ls -1 $path`;
close $fileh;
print "Saved Serials!";
```

Now all I want is to read in the data in the file into an array, and then loop through each value to complete a task. I can't figure out how to do this...

Currently I am entering the numbers manually in the code into an array, like:

```
@ser_list = (100,101,102,103,...);
```

As stated above, I instead want to automatically write the file names (numbers) using the `ls` command line query and read them back into the script from there. 
If there is a way of doing this without having to make a separate file of values that would be great.

The array is called @ser_list in the example, and from there I am reading the next $ser_num from the array and working with that in the loop.

```
foreach $ser_num (@ser_list) {....}
```

Thank you all in advance for your help and patience!

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `ls` in a Perl program. You can use [glob](http://p3rl.org/glob) instead:

```
my @files = glob "$path/*";
```

If you need to work with the paths and filenames, check [Path::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Path::Tiny).

To read lines with paths into an array, just use

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die $!;
chomp( my @paths = <$fh> );
```

See [open](http://p3rl.org/open), [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp), and [readline](http://p3rl.org/readline) for details.

Comment: The default `glob()` is based on `csh` and does not handle spaces in filenames. If the filenames have spaces, replace the `glob()`function with `use File::Glob qw( :bsd_glob );`

Comment: @shawnhcorey: It doesn't handle spaces in its argument, filenames with spaces are ok. You need to backslash spaces in the argument if you don't want them to become separators.

Comment: You're correct. It's spaces in dirnames that cause the most trouble. When walking down a directory tree, spaces in dirnames must be escaped. Or use `:bsd_glob` and not worry about it.

Comment: Additionally he can use: `opendir(my $DH, "."); chomp(my @f = readdir($DH)); closedir $DH;` (don't forget about `.` and `..`).

Comment: @3ED: `chomp` with `readdir`? If your dirnames end in newlines, you want to keep them.

Comment: @choroba: Sounds legit, and `chomp` is unnecessary there.